# How to import MUI component in different name?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Really short question, how do I import `Table` from MUI in a different name, as the name of my components is `Table.js` and there is a conflict because the way you import MUI `Table` is like this:

```
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
```

and obviously there is a conflict because then there are two elements in a component that have Table identifier.

Is there any way to import `Table` in a different name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import { Table as CustomTableName } from "@mui/material";
```

or

```
import CustomTableName from "@mui/material/Table";
```

Answer (score -1):

You're using default import, the name of the component can be anything you want, the convention is to use `MuiComponent` if there are duplicated names in your file:

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import MuiTable from "@mui/material/Table";

const Table = styled(MuiTable)(...);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import {Table as YourTableName} from "@mui/material/Table";
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 